# c++ strptime ignores Timezone when parsing

Tags: c++, parsing, time, timezone, strptime

When I run the following code **strptime** seems to ignore the timezone value. Just sets value of the local timezone (which is +10).

This is the output, (Running on Linux, compiled with gcc 4.6.3):

```
-----------2013-04-24T9:47:06+400 - %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z
TM Break    H:9 is DST:0 GMT Off:0
The epoch value:    1366760826
DateTime in String:     04/24/13 - 09:47AM +1000

-----------2013-04-24T11:47:06+800 - %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z
TM Break    H:11 is DST:0 GMT Off:36000
The epoch value:    1366768026
DateTime in String:     04/24/13 - 11:47AM +1000

-----------2013-04-24T9:47:06+0 - %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z
TM Break    H:9 is DST:0 GMT Off:36000
The epoch value:    1366760826
DateTime in String:     04/24/13 - 09:47AM +1000

-----------2013-04-24T9:47:06+4 - %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z
TM Break    H:9 is DST:0 GMT Off:36000
The epoch value:    1366760826
DateTime in String:     04/24/13 - 09:47AM +1000
```

**This is the code:**

```
void date_Test(){
    string dateStrings[] = {"2013-04-24T9:47:06+400"
                          , "2013-04-24T11:47:06+800"
                          , "2013-04-24T9:47:06+0"
                          , "2013-04-24T9:47:06+4"};
    string formatStrings[] = {"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"
                            , "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"
                            , "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"
                            , "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"};

process_Timezone(dateStrings, formatStrings);
}

void process_Timezone(string dateStrings[], string formatStrings[]){
    int num = 4; 

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        cout << endl << "-----------" << dateStrings[i] << " - " << formatStrings[i] << endl;
        tm *dtm = new tm;
        strptime(dateStrings[i].c_str(), formatStrings[i].c_str(), dtm);
        cout << "TM Break \tH:" << dtm->tm_hour << " is DST:" << dtm->tm_isdst << " GMT Off:"  << dtm->tm_gmtoff << endl;
        time_t ep_dt = mktime(dtm);
        cout << "The epoch value: \t" << ep_dt << endl;
        char buffer[40];
        strftime(buffer, 40,"%x - %I:%M%p %z", dtm);
        cout << "DateTime in String: \t" << buffer << endl;
        delete dtm;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601` your one and three digit timezone offsets are not valid ISO 8601 values (the form used by `strptime` at least on Linux), which requires `hh[:][mm]` as the format.

Comment: I have tried variations like 0400, 04:00 none of them have worked, could not find even an example online of someone using it

Comment: hey any luck on this, i have the same problem .. how create time_t from string having timezone

Answer (score 2):

Might be late, but `strptime` does correctly parse the `%z` specifier, it stores it in `tm.tm_gmtoff` variable. This variable is not in the standard, but a gnu extension. `mktime` does not make use of this variable.

You can try

```
strptime(<time_string>, dtm);
std::cout << dtm->tm_gmtoff;
```

to see the parsed time offset.

Note `.tm_gmtoff` is in second, so to get the correct epoch time, you can do

```
auto offset = dtm->tm_gmtoff;
auto _epoch = mktime(dtm);
auto final_epoch = _epoch + offset
```

Sources

- https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Broken_002ddown-Time.html
- https://github.com/andikleen/glibc/blob/master/time/strptime_l.c#L749

Comment: This helped me, so have an upvote, but I don't think it's quite right unless you're running in UTC.  To explain why, I needed more space than a comment, so submitted my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @Nguyen Ha Kien helped me, but to get the right epoch time, I needed to factor in my local UTC offset too, after it's been filled in by mktime, and not override libc's determination of whether DST was active at the specified time here:

```
        int offset = dtm->tm_gmtoff;
        // Ask libc to work out whether the local timezone is in DST at this time.
        dtm->tm_isdst = -1;
        time_t ep_dt = mktime(dtm);
        ep_dt -= offset - dtm->tm_gmtoff;
```

int rather than auto just because I'm compiling on a 2011 era setup, hopefully like that used by pt123 originally, to show that the answer from Mark B gets strptime to parse tm_gmtoff for me:

```
(ia32)martind@sirius:~/playpen$ ls /lib/libc-2.11.3.so 
/lib/libc-2.11.3.so
(ia32)martind@sirius:~/playpen$ gcc -v
...
gcc version 4.4.5 (Debian 4.4.5-8) 
(ia32)martind@sirius:~/playpen$ g++ c-strptime-ignores-timezone-when-parsing.cpp 
(ia32)martind@sirius:~/playpen$ ./a.out

-----------2013-04-24T9:47:06+0400 - %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z
TM Break    H:9 is DST:0 GMT Off:14400
```

The only additional code was:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void process_Timezone(string dateStrings[], string formatStrings[]);
void date_Test();
int main(){
    date_Test();
}
```